# How to get the ProgID of an installed application by a command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

There are some applications that are not shown by name but by ProgID, is there any way to get the name of that key in the registry?

[image: example]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/-progid--key

Comment: Where are these applications shown?

Comment: There are several, including Blender, antivirus, mouse software, etc. I need to get that ID but without going manually to the registry, the problem is that when you install the program generates different ProgID, it is not always the same number.

Comment: Where are you seeing these progids? Are they visible anywhere in a GUI? RegisteredApplications?

Comment: Nowhere in the GUI does this number appear

I see them in the uninstall key.
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{25DF2B02-C761-49C6-81D9-B29B7838A9AC}

Comment: I don't know if this Powershell script can help you or not ? [Get-ProgID](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/get-progid/) or This [Get-ProgID.ps1](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Discovery/1.0.1/Content/Get-ProgID.ps1)

Comment: Thanks, although this returns all the ProgIDs, I just need a specific one to save it in a variable

Comment: @Dave you can filter by this example and i don't know what is the name that you are looking for ? Just an example : `Get-ProgID | Where-Object { $_.ProgID -like "*Namethat you Know*" }`

Comment: That's the problem, the key name is not always the same. It is generated randomly at each new installation. I need to access a value inside that uninstall key but I don't see a way to get that address from the registry (because of that ProgID)

Comment: Is it the uninstall entry you are interested in and not really the progid?

Comment: I know the registry values inside that key but since I don't know the ProgID I can't access it

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{Here is the ProgID}

With other programs there is no problem because it shows the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft recommends that ISVs create progids in the form of `Company.Appname` or `Company.Appname.Suffix` but that is irrelevant since the uninstall key name you are interested in is not actually a progid at all! Progids are used by file/protocol associations and COM. Some browsers use `Appname.Hash` where the hash is calculated by [hashing the path](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1709430#c3).

The uninstall key name can be anything (but hopefully does not collide with anyone else). MSI installers use a GUID (this GUID maps to something MSI related, [the product code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/uninstall-registry-key)). Other installers often use some variation of the application name.

You should enumerate all the uninstall registry keys and compare the start of the key name to whatever app you are interested in and/or look at the strings (like DisplayName, Publisher and UninstallString) inside the uninstall key.

Powershell knows how to map the MSI GUIDs:

```
get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Format-Table IdentifyingNumber, Name
```